# required condition is false: IsFormatSampleRateAndChannelCountValid(format) got in react-native-community voice

Tags: ios, react-native

2021-06-21 15:55:37.951823+0530 Provider[10264:187500] [javascript] Text To speech started
2021-06-21 15:55:37.956761+0530 Provider[10264:203268] [avae]            AVAEInternal.h:76    required condition is false: [AVAEGraphNode.mm:823:CreateRecordingTap: (IsFormatSampleRateAndChannelCountValid(format))]
2021-06-21 15:55:37.958606+0530 Provider[10264:203268] [Error] - com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio required condition is false: IsFormatSampleRateAndChannelCountValid(format)
2021-06-21 15:55:37.978865+0530 Provider[10264:187500] [javascript] 'onSpeechStart: ', undefined
2021-06-21 15:55:37.979514+0530 Provider[10264:187500] [javascript] 'onSpeechError: ', 'required condition is false: IsFormatSampleRateAndChannelCountValid(format)'

Answer (score 1):

If You get this error run the code inside a real ios device this will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a mic connected. I had this error on my mac mini because I had no connected microphone. The reason it works on a real ios device is because there's a built in mic